# How can a (local) label end outside it's own segment (TASM 8086)?

Tags: assembly, x86-16, tasm

My professor often uses this pattern of writing his code where DS is involved.

```
ASSUME CS:CODE,DS:DATA

DATA SEGMENT
[...]
DATA ENDS

CODE SEGMENT
START:
[...]
CODE ENDS
END START
END
```

According to his concept, we do this so that the assembler checks for the data segment. But I can't really agree on it without a valid explanation...

How does a label end outside a segment?

Why can't the assembler check for the DS without it?

Are labels in assembly different?

Comment: I don't understand the question. The only label there is `start:` and that has nothing to do with `DS`. Also the assembler does not check anything, the `ASSUME` instructs it to believe something without checking.

Comment: Hey Jester..ASSUME is really not of any concern in my case...My only concern is how can an LABEL end outside a segment...

Comment: Which label is it and why do you think it's outside of a segment? So you mean the `END START`? That sets the entry point for your program. In any case, labels are not constrained to segments for obvious reasons. Otherwise you couldn't reference a piece of data from code, for example.

Comment: Does SEGMENT expand to something? I doubt it does...

Comment: Entry point at END? Could you please elaborate?

Comment: I also don't get your question. The only label is `START` and, like every other label, it doesn't end. Labels don't end. the `END START` is not the end of the label is setting the entry-point (you could also have used a number instead of a label). `END` alone just marks the end of the program (never used it, don't know if it is actually useful). Segments instruct the assembler to make sure the constraints (order, alignment, bitness) for the code/data inside is satisfied. Also, they can map to the underlying binary format. What does it mean "The assembler checks for the data segment"?

Comment: Thanks for clearing my concept...Is there any way we can do it without a label...something like `END CODE`

Comment: Theoretically that could work, meaning start the program at the start of the `CODE` segment. But I don't think that's accepted.

Comment: It treats it as a number...a pointer apparently

Comment: Is SEGMENT a macro?

Comment: which expands to something like `: some mysterious code`

Comment: The errors I get claim that CODE is a label...I tried using a number instead and I got an error as if I tried to create a label

Comment: What's wrong with using a label? Anyway, SEGMENT is not a macro and it does not emit any code. It just instructs the assembler to place the following stuff into the given segment in the object file. PS: you can omit the label, you can use `END` alone and set the entry point on the linker command line. Or use the default label name.

Comment: I am trying to use as few lines as possible.. :)

Comment: Could you please post the details you have given in the form of an answer? You can start by saying that I had got my concepts completely wrong and then start explaining how the assembler actually views the asm code.

Comment: Btw, Can we create a segment by declaring it's start address?

Comment: You probably want to read [the TASM manual](http://bitsavers.informatik.uni-stuttgart.de/pdf/borland/turbo_assembler/Turbo_Assembler_Version_5_Users_Guide.pdf). You can place a segment at an address with `AT` but that will prevent you from putting anything inside it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`END START` isn't "the end" of the `start` label.  Labels themselves don't have ends or lengths or scopes.  (Use `proc foo` / `endproc` for that, unless that's only MASM not TASM).

`END START` is the end of the whole asm file (parsing stops after that). **`END label` also sets the entry point = the specified label**.  It's a weird name for a directive with that purpose, but TASM is very old.

(The assembler can put metadata in the `.obj` file to tell the linker the entry point symbol name, if the assembler doesn't emit a `.exe` directly.)

---

Think of labels as zero-width tags that you can reference from elsewhere, nothing more.

If you have a block of code for a function you want to call, you stick a label right before it so you can `call` to that point.  The machine code for that function has some size, but the label doesn't; it's merely labeling the start of the block.  (So a label always has exactly 1 address.)

Comment: Is there any way by which I can force the debugger to start from a particular label after executing the instructions prior to it?

Comment: @NephewofStackoverflow: if the instruction before a label just executed, the instruction after that label will already execute next (execution doesn't stop at labels, they're just a way to attach names to addresses and don't affect the fact that 2 instructions are adjacent).  Or if that's not what you mean, most debuggers have a way to modify IP/EIP/RIP to effectively change control flow on the fly, like how you can change data registers.

Comment: I use Turbo Debugger to debug my .asm code, so I just want to ignore debugging the first two instructions (initialization of DS)...I know it's not a big overhead to be concerned about...But is there any way to tell the debugger to just execute the first two instructions by default...maybe my passing some parameters to `TD` or....

Comment: @NephewofStackoverflow: Set a breakpoint on the third instruction instead of the first?  IDK, I don't use that debugger.  (I use GDB under Linux on 64-bit or 32-bit code.)

Comment: How would you do it with the assembler you're using?

Comment: @NephewofStackoverflow: Oh, since you mention doing it via the assembler instead of in the debugger, you could put an `int3` instruction somewhere (a hardcoded breakpoint that you don't have to set every time you restart the debugger).  Then the GDB `run` command to start the program will stop at that `int3` instruction after doing whatever init stuff, if you haven't set any breakpoint earlier.  Or of course you could set a breakpoint at whatever instruction you want with `b 12` to set a breakpoint on line 12, or `b *0x401008` if that happened to be the address of the insn I wanted.

Comment: What are the tools that are used while developing assembly code? Do you think there is any repetitive thing you do which don't change until you want it to? Actually I was developing a open-source software as a replacement for the existing one...

Comment: @NephewofStackoverflow: A text editor, either vim for emacs depending on my mood.  And a terminal window to build + run it (with nasm && ld) and profile the result, usually with `perf stat`.  I don't write large programs in asm; mostly performance experiments to find out what I want to get a C compiler to emit.  (e.g. to file missed optimization bug reports, or to tune my C code to get better asm.)  Sometimes I fire up GDB to single-step something with starti / si.  (my is pretty simple: GDBinit [Set default TUI layout in .gdbinit?](//stackoverflow.com/q/49800774))

Comment: Thanks @Peter Cordes. Are there any other tools which people rarely use but is still useful? Are you on Discord or some other platform where we can discuss about this further...You can reply to me as and when you get time

Comment: @NephewofStackoverflow: no, I don't generally hang out on Discord.  And if you're developing obsolete 16-bit programs, I don't have any suggestions.  I've never used TASM.  I've heard BOCHS has a good built-in debugger for OS development, but Turbo Debugger is presumably fine for user-space programs that aren't creating a GDT and switching to protected mode.  Obscure things: I've sometimes used IACA for static performance analysis.  LLVM-MCA can do the same thing.